# Gettin the jQuery the :not() selector to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have added this variable

```
var spellSpace = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('.highlight-problem:not(.right-word)');
```

and for some reason it will not work in this code

```
$('.next-question').click(function () {
    $('td').removeClass('highlight-problem');
    var r = rndWord;
    while (r == rndWord) {
        rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
    }
    $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('highlight-problem');
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wrong-letter').removeClass('wrong-word').removeClass('right-letter');
    var spellSpace = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('.highlight-problem:not(.right-word)');
    if (spellSpace) {
        addMedia();
    }
});
```

It just will not return the addMedia() function and I do not know why

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: just change `hasClass` to `is`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasClass` gets a class name as an argument, not a selector. You may use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead:

```
var spellSpace = $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]')
    .is('.highlight-problem:not(.right-word)');
```

Or maybe the following:

```
var spellSpace = $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name
    + '"].highlight-problem:not(.right-word)').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery `hasClass` function can't accept css selector : http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Use `is` : http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can try to use jQuery [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter.

```
var spellSpace = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('highlight-problem').not('.right-word');
```